# Select All That Has The Same Prefix SPARQL

Tags: sparql

I would like to return all triples where all subjects have the same prefix.

```
PREFIX dv: <http://example.org/example_vocabulary:>

SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM <http://example.org/dataset.example>
WHERE {
    ?s ?p ?o .
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should treat the URI as a string and basically filter your variable based on what you need. Since you are looking for a prefix, you can use `strstarts`. For example, something along these lines will work:

```
PREFIX dv: <http://example.org/example_vocabulary>
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM <http://example.org/dataset.example>
WHERE {
    ?s ?p ?o .
    filter strstarts(str(?s),str(dv:))
}
```

You should read up on [string function](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-strings).

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly. Reading about string function now!